# How to reuse the code if only the base class is different in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two classes, all the codes are the same, except for the base class. How could I refactor them and reuse the code? some_code_1 and some_code_2 are the same in two classes. I'm new to C++, thank you for giving me any suggestions.

```
<template class C>
class A : Base_1<C>
{
    private:
        using Base = Base_1<C>;
    public:
        using Base::Base;
       
        method(pa1, pa2, pa3)
        {
            // some_same_code_1
            Base::some_method(pa1, pa2, pa3);
            // some_same_code_2
        }
}

<template class C>
class A : Base_2<C>
{
    private:
        using Base = Base_2<C>;
    public:
        using Base::Base;
       
        method(pa1, pa2, pa3, pa4, pa5)
        {
            // some_same_code_1
            Base::some_method(pa1, pa2, pa3, pa4, pa5);
            // some_same_code_2
        }
}
```

Comment: Not nearly enough information. What are the base classes? What are these classes supposed to do? What are the child classes supposed to do? A refactor that you're talking about requires some actual analysis, not band-aid code.

Comment: Code of these two classes do not appear to be the same.

Comment: This feels a lot like you shouldn't have inheritance at all here but rather use composition. Without more info that's hard to tell though

Comment: sorry, i haven't written c++ before, i don't know how to ask clearly. The base classes are some basic operation, for example,  calculate matrix multiplication, and the child classes are some variant operation. The different between Base_1 and Base_2 is Base_1 is doing exact calculation and Base_2 realizes some approximate calculation. And I want to implement the approximate version of derived class B.

Comment: Please don't make large changes to the question after getting an answer. The point of SO is to preserve knowledge for future readers, and the large changes will make existing answers meaningless for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a template:

```
template <typename Base>
class Foo : Base
{
  public:
    // some_code_1
    Base::some_method(pa1, pa2, pa3);
    // some_code_2
};

using A = Foo<Base_1>;
using B = Foo<Base_2>;
```

Here, `using A = Foo<Base_1>;` makes `A` a shorthand for `Foo<Base_1>`. Alternatively you can write `Foo<Base_1>` every time you need your class. Same for `B` and `Foo<Base_2>`.

Comment: thank you, when calling some_method, the number of arguments are different in Base_1 and Base_2, how could i resolve it?

Comment: @KikiDu Oh, I didn't notice that the arguments were different. Then you can make `A` and `B` classes inheriting from `Foo<Base_1>` and `Foo<Base_2>` respectively (don't forget to inherit constructors). Then put the common code into `Foo`, and the parts that differ into `A` and `B`.

Comment: how to put the common code into Foo? make them (same_code_1, same_code_2) as methods?

Comment: @KikiDu Maybe, it depends on what you're doing.